# Next.js build error: Export encountered errors on following paths

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This error appears when I build.

```
info  - Generating static pages (15/15)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /routine/RoutineLists
    at /home/corepen/Desktop/Project 1/rouDDine-client/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:31:1106
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

This isn't the right solution, but I erased 'RoutineLIsts.js' file.
And I don't think this is the right solution.
Even there was still another error.

How can I fix this error? Here's `next.config.js` file's contents.

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      'https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20191004/ourlarge/pngtree-person-icon-png-image_1788612.jpg',
    ],
  },
};

const withImages = require('next-images');
module.exports = withImages();

const withVideos = require('next-videos')
module.exports = withVideos()
```

How should we deal with this?

This is the overall folder structure.

---

I found onething, when i assigned a static value and it was built, but I never wanted it.

```
const routine1 = {id :1, name : '123'}

  return (
    <>
    <Link href={`/routine/${routine1.id}`}>
     <a>
       <RoutineContainer
        id={routine1.id}
        onClick={(e) => {getMyRoutine(e)}}
        >
        <img id={routine1.id} src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_url}/${img}`}></img>
          <RoutineItem id={routine1.id}>
            <RoutineTitle id={routine1.id}>{routine1.name}</RoutineTitle>
          </RoutineItem>
        </RoutineContainer>
      </a>
    </Link>
    <DeleteButton id={routine1.id} onClick={() => deleteHandler(routine1.id)}>-</DeleteButton>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: If you want, I'll reveal GitHub Repository. thank you..

Comment: What does your `/routine/RoutineLists` file look like? Also, the way your `next.config.js` is setup is incorrect, you should have a single `module.exports`, i.e., `module.exports = withImages(withVideos({ /* Your config object here */}))`.

Comment: @juliomalves '({ /* Your config object here */})`,  Do you mean the picture and video files that I want? Then should I put in the there?

Comment: I mean the other object you have in the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this code, you should use baseurl to show Image

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      'https://png.pngtree.com',
    ],
  },
};
```